# Using gdb to check register's values

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

How can I see what values the registers hold? I have the following line of assembly:

```
 mov 0x8(%rax), %rax
 cpm %ebx, (%rax)
```

Using the command:

```
 (gdb) p/x $ebx
 (gdb) p/x $rbx
 $3 = 0xb
```

I get the value that is stored in this register. However, when I try to see what it is stored int the memory location (%rax) I have the following problem:

```
(gdb) display *(int *)$rax
Disabling display 10 to avoid infinite recursion.
10: *(int *)$rax = Cannot access memory at address 0x17
```

I cannot not understand why this happens and moreover how to find out what (%rax) has in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see the values of the registers just use

```
print $rax
info register $rax
info register
```

In your case it seems `rax` contains the number `0x17` and the debugger cannot access this location. Please make sure that `rax` contains a valid address pointing to an integer.

You should use `print` instead of `display` if you want to take a quick view. Dont abuse the `display` command. You can use it if you need a kind of watchdog for an expression.

Here you find a quick reference

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what sort of CPU you are using (x86?), but do memory accesses have to be aligned? This would mean that you could access 0x08, 0x10, 0x18, 0x20 and so on (or maybe it's 32 bit words which would be 0x00, 0x20, 0x40 and so on). This could be an incorrect answer though depending on your architecture. Also, what is the registry tag for? The windows registry doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: I am using 64 bit machine; that's why i have %rax instead of %eax. And sorry about the tag, I though it was for this kind of registers

Comment: What architecture? Itanium, SPARC or POWER?

Comment: Probably add the architecture as a tag to the question.